# Remove multiple elements from 2 lists at same index position

Tags: python, list

**Question:**

I have two longs lists, ~50,000 elements in each, that are the exact same size. List a contains 8 values (all different) followed by 16 zeroes which repeats until the end of the list, list b is a the result of a trigonometric function performed on the first list.

I'd like to remove all the zeroes from list a, and then every corresponding index from list b.

**Example** (all 1's and 2's for simplicity):

```
a = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2] ...

b = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2] ...
```

**To become**

```
a = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2] ...

b = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2] ...
```

In reality, every single element has a different value apart from zeroes, so I was thinking of a loop that scans list a for zeroes, and removes the elements at that index from both lists.

This is what I've come up with so far but I get an error 'list index out of range'

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == 0:
        a.remove(a[i])
        b.remove(b[i])
    else:
        pass
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes they do. List 'a' has a repeating structure every 24 elements. There are 8 values (all different, but I've used a '1' in the example) followed by 16 zeroes. List 'b' is has a value at every index (again I've used a '1' here).

Where I've put a 2, this indicates the start of the 2nd repeat. In reality it repeats over 2000 times. The key thing is that every non-zero element has a completely different value, only the zeroes in list a are consistent and repeating. EDIT: the comment before was deleted so ignore this

Answer (score 3):

With `numpy`'s [fancy indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) you can do it with a couple of lines of code:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(a)
b = np.array(b)[a != 0].tolist()
a = a[a != 0].tolist()
```

And consider using `numpy` if you're working with large portions of data.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I do use numpy for many things, I'll start considering it for my lists

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2]
b = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2]
x = zip(a,b)
x = filter(lambda item: item[0] != 0, x)
a,b = map(list,zip(*x))
```

use `zip` to combine list a and b, the result looks like:

> [(1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (2, 2), (2, 2)]

then filter the `tuple` whose first element is 0.
last, unzip the result and convert to `list`

Before Python 3.0 you'd want to use itertools.izip if you have large numbers of elements.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is

```
a = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2]
b = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2]
new_a = []
new_b = []
for i,j in zip(a,b):
    if i:
        new_a.append(i)
        new_b.append(j)
a = new_a
b = new_b
print(a)
print(b)
```

which produces

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

Another (quicker) solution using the same approach but with list comprehensions is

```
new_a = [i for i in a if i]
b = [j for i,j in zip(a,b) if i]
a = new_a
```

Note: as you can see, there is no need to use indexing nor to look for the zero elements in the list on every iteration

Answer (score 0):

this is better way i think for removing zeros:
**sol 1**

```
while a.count(0):
     a.remove(0)

print a #[1,1,1,...,2]
```

or you can do this:
**sol2**

```
for i in range(len(a)-1,-1,-1):
      if a[i] == 0:
          a.remove(a[i])
          b.remove(b[i])
```

the reason your code is not working , is that when you start from zero and then use range(len(a)) assume range is 25, then you remove the 4th element, now your range is 24 and your list no longer has 25th element! so when in you for loop, i eqauls 24 you get index error(because by that time your list is smaller), but if you move from end of your list, when your list gets smaller,this problem won't occure

Comment: nice, but define `better` please. What is the complexity of your solution?

Comment: Thank you, I also need to remove the elements from list b at the same index position(s) of all the zeroes

Comment: @RichardHall : the second is what you want exactly !

Comment: @RichardHall checkout sol2

Comment: the indentation is wrong. And most of all, it still has to look for the element in the list on every iteration, unnecessary. Time it.

Comment: @Pynchia : indentation is correct!
this is o(n^2) and I think there's no better solution to do this!
if the list is sorted, maybe o(n*log(n)) can be achieved!

Comment: yes, indentation is `now` correct. As for the algorithm: as I suggested, time it. I am sure there are better ways (see my humble answer, but there may be even better ones).

Comment: @Pynchia sol2 slightly worked although I now have 2 lists with the same size as the orignal, but all the results are pushed to the front and then followed by 1000's of 0's. Is there a way to fully delete the index position and shift everything backwards? In the end I'd like 2 lists that are 1/3 as long as before (keep 8, remove 16) 

EDIT: Ignore that, I had my list labels reversed. This works too, thanks!!